# getElementsByClassName not effecting multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color, getelementsbyclassname

```
<a id="backgroundenamel_realbutton_powderblue"
 href="javascript:set_radio('radio_bgenamel_powderblue');" 
 class="radio-picture-enamel" style="background-color: #97b4d2;"
 onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('cx00ringbuilder_topinsidecolor_img')[0].style.backgroundColor='#97b4d2';">&nbsp;</a>
```

The above is supposed to change the color for multiple divs. I need a way for it to do all the divs. I know I have to change the [0] to an array or something but I don't know how.... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript), [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Comment: I would also add that using inline JS is terrible for code maintainability. Separating HTML and JS makes debugging a lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign a value to multiple objects at once. Loop through the objects:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('cx00ringbuilder_topinsidecolor_img');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.backgroundColor='#97b4d2';
}
```