# HTML Parsing using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I am trying to get parse HTML document.

this is the HTML:

```
<h1>
<span class="memName fn" itemprop="name">Ankur Arora</span>
<span class="display-none" itemprop="image">http://photos1.meetupstatic.com/photos/member/3/8/f/8/member_249974584.jpeg</span>
<span class="display-none" itemprop="url">http://www.meetup.com/Meetup-API-Testing/members/191523682/</span>
</h1>
```

I need to get the picture and the name.

I try this code:

```
var name = document.querySelector("memName fn").name;
```

Anyone can help me? I'm new in javaScript...

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to get the inner text of the targetted elements?

Comment: @JeroenBellemans yes!!

Answer (score 1):

To get the inner text, you can use the `text()` function, like this:

HTML:

```
<span class="memName fn">Ankur Arora</span>
```

Jquery:

```
var memName = $(".memName").text();
console.log(memName); // Via console log
alert(memName); // Alert it
```

Comment: Hello Jeroen Bellemans, thans for your answer...
please see the comment in the answer of Chris Breaks...

Comment: So what exactly is the problem then?

Comment: there is possible without jquery?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with jQuery. Just include it in your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then use `.text()` or `.html()` to extract the content of the `span`-elements

```
var pictureLink = $("span[itemprop='image']").text();
//.html() also gets the html-elements inside
var name = $("span[itemprop='name']").html();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bh9mebru/

Comment: Hello Chris Breaks, thanks for your answer, but its not working...
first I need to search the class in the page no??

Comment: I can't think of a way why this wouldn't be working (see the jsfiddle-link). Do you get javascript-errors? Generally speaking: You can address elements in different ways. for example by id, by classname, by position relative to other elements, or in this case by your unique attribute `itemprop`. a good way to debug your script is by passing out data with `console.log("data")` at vital positions.

Comment: there is possible without jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use innerHTML to get the text.

```
<span id="memId" class="memName fn">Ankur Arora</span>
```

document.getElementsByClassName('memName') - This will give the list of elements having the class 'memName'

To get the first element's inner text use `document.getElementsByClassName('memName')[0].innerHTML`

or access by id .

```
document.getElementById('memId').innerHTML
```