# Delete tabel row with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I Need to delete a table row with pure javascript. The table has only a class name, no id.

Here is a fiddle with my first try:

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('table');
while(table.rows.length > 0) {
    table.deleteRow(1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5s0w6cwL/

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: `var table = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0]`. See https://jsfiddle.net/5s0w6cwL/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get first `element`.

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0];
```

because `document.getElementsByClassName` method returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

```js
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0];
table.deleteRow(1);
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>delete me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```