# How can I repair this?

Tags: javascript

I want to change:

```
<b class="added-points">0</b>
```

in my website using javascript. I searched and found

```
document.getElementById("added-points").innerHTML = "9999999999999";
```

but it is for id and I search for class. How to do it?

Comment: `class` != `id`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("added-points")[0].innerHTML = "9999999999999";
```

```html
<b class="added-points">0</b>
```

you will set the first (`[0]`) element in the array of elements with the class `added-points` to 9999999999999. Note `document.getElementsByClassName` gives you an array result even if there is just one item found.

Comment: The text is not chanigng.

Comment: But the text is the same. It's not changing. I don't have any error. It show  "9999999999999".

Comment: Fixed answer again to adjust for array of nodes and added more explanation.

Comment: I saw it when I find the ansfer :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `document.querySelector(".added-points")`.

Comment: but, how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

in chrome

```
document.querySelector(".added-points").innerHTML = "9999999999999";
```

in IE

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*'), item => {
  if (item.className.split(' ').indexOf('added-points') > -1) {
    item.innerHTML = '9999999999999'
  }
})
```