# How to get Javascript's "getElementsByClassName()" to work?

Tags: javascript

When I do this, everything works just fine:

```
function openTab(tabName)
{
    document.getElementById("divUsers").className = "invisible";
    document.getElementById("divGroups").className = "invisible";
    document.getElementById("divZFSPools").className = "invisible";
    document.getElementById("divShares").className = "invisible";

    document.getElementById(tabName).className = "visible";
}
```

But when I do *this*, nothing happens:

```
function openTab(tabName)
{
    var targetTab, activeTab;

    // Get the div:
    targetTab = document.getElementById(tabName);

    // If it is the active tab, return:
    if(targetTab.style.display.className == "visible");
        return;

    // No, it is not the active tab:
    document.getElementsByClassName("visible")[0].className = "invisible";

  // Make the target tab visible:
  document.getElementById(tabName).className = "visible";

}
```

FYI: "visible" and "invisible" are two CSS class names.

Does anyone have idea why? How can I achieve the desktop tab control behaviour using HTML and Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Is it a typo or you did it intentionally `if(targetTab.style.display.className == "visible");` see the **semicolon** at the end of `if`

Comment: Yes, I am using PyCharm CE (on FreeBSD) as my IDE and unfortunately it does not help much with typos. I removed the semicolon and it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: The way you're attributing a class name it isn't recommended, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't misunderstood you question just remove the `;` after your `if` condition because a simple typo (`;`) can make huge difference to your code.

Assume,

```
if (0 === 1); { alert("Hello World") }

// equivalent to:

if (0 === 1) /*do nothing*/ ;
alert ("Hello World");
```

> This code will alert "Hello World", but not because 0 equals 1, but
>   because of the semicolon. It makes JavaScript think that you have an
>   empty statement there, and everything to the right of it is treated as
>   no longer belonging to the if conditional and thus independent of it.

**Source** : https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/507f6dd09266b70200000d7e

So on your code it will be like this,

```
//If it is the active tab, return:
if(targetTab.style.display.className == "visible"); 
    return;                                    //^^ remove this semicolon
```