# get element, javascript, html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<cfset fedexReply = fedexShipper.processShipmentRequest(
            shipToName = "#form.TO_Company#",
            shipToCompany = "#form.TO_Company#",
            shipToPhone = "#form.TO_Telephone#",
            shipToEmail = "#form.TO_Email#",
            shipToAddress1 = "#form.TO_Address1#",
            shipToCity = "#form.TO_City#",
            shipToState = "#form.TO_State#",
            shipToZip = "#form.TO_ZIPCode#",
            shipToCountry = "#form.TO_Country#",
            shipToResidential = #form.ResidentialAddress#,
```

How can I get the value of `ship` To `Residential` so that I can use it in my other form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Comment: please specify this code is html or javascript...?

Comment: java script sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a server-side code, maybe CodeFusion?

It will render a form for you with an input field like this:

```
<input name="shipToResidential">
```

If there is also an ID with the same attribute value, for example:

```
<input name="shipToResidential" id="shipToResidential">
```

Then you can just use document.getElementById('shipToResidential')

Otherwise you'll have to traverse the document:

```
var os=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var addr='';
for (var i=0;i<os.length;i++){
  if (os[i].attributes['name']&&os[i].attributes['name'].value=='shipToResidential')
  addr=os[i].attributes['name'].value;
}
```

Comment: i will try it, thanks a lot for your help, its coldfusion btw :)