# I cannot take the item from the array in JavaScript despite having the array

Tags: javascript

When I type this

```
var sectionIntro = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
```

I get a list of my HTML.

However, when I try to take the first item in the array:

```
var sectionIntro = document.getElementsByClassName("section")[0];
```

I get `undefined`.

What is happening?

My HTML:

```
<section class="section">

        <div id="box1">
            <p class="theQuote">" We ignited, now you spark "</p>
            <p class="theQuoteW">~ Alumni</p>
        </div>

    <div class="introduction">
        <div id="box2">                

            <h4 id="intro">Intro</h4>
```

I want to take the `class="section"` using:

```
var sectionIntro = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Comment: try find out what being collected first `var sectionIntro = document.getElementsByClassName("section"); console.log(sectionIntro)`

Comment: yes  I did this in the console in my web browser. I got the array tho

Comment: It returns an `HTMLCollection`, not an array, can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: done, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

so the answer to this problem is the placement of javascript script in the html. I placed the script in the head, it should be at the end of the body