# Javascript: Get input by its Class Name & Type Simultaneously

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway I can get an input by its class name? For example I have this html code below:

```
<span class="inputClass">
   <input type="checkbox"/>
<span>
```

I would like to see if that input is selected using its class name. There is no option I can give it an ID because we do not have access to this source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Comment: `document.querySelector('.inputClass > input').id = 'whateverYouLike';`

Comment: Also very similar to [How to Select Element That Does Not Have Specific Class](/21975881/how-to-select-element-that-does-not-have-specific-class)

Comment: $(".inputClass input").val(); May this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `document.querySelector('.inputClass > input[type="checkbox"]')`.

```js
const inputEle = document.querySelector('.inputClass > input');
console.log('isChecked: ', inputEle.checked);

inputEle.addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<span class="inputClass">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
<span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the input from the children of the parent class

```
.inputClass > input[type=checkbox]
```

Below is working snippet.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.inputClass > input[type=checkbox]').checked)
```

```html
<span class="inputClass">
   <input type="checkbox"/>
<span>
```