# Hide Element when hover Element Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a DIV that needs to be displayed/hide whenever i hover a menu item.

Here it is my website: [Website](https://nycphoto.pixl.work/)

The Blug light section should be displayed only when I hover the Photo Booths menu on the header.

I have tried the following code on JSFiddle which it works but when i use it on my site it doesn't work

```
<script>
let test = document.getElementByClassName(".menu-item.menu-item-7912");

test.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
document.getElementById('test2').style.display = 'none';
});

test.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {

document.getElementById('mega-menu-customized').style.display = 'block';

});

</script>
```

I have tried using getElementByClassName but without success. Any ideas of how to make it work?

Comment: let's see the fiddle

Comment: There is getElementsByClassName but not getElementByClassName available. You can refer link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name to understand this.

Comment: If you want to provide multiple classes, you can do so by document.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2"). You will get HTMLNodeCollection upon which you can use Array.from to get collection in array.

Comment: @quantumPuter here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/alejoblue/co7dq1yt/1/

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting DOM node in test variable, one problem I can see in your code is:

```
let test = document.getElementsByClassName(".menu-item.menu-item-7912");
```

Should be:

```
let test = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item, menu-item-7912");
```

We do not use dot before class name and multiple classes can be separated by comma like:

```
let test = document.getElementsByClassName("class1, class2, class3");
```

Comment: I just tested this using the ClassName, but it seems im doing something wrong because it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/alejoblue/dLcqru52/
All the elements have to use ClassName, because the other element i want to show is using ID. Using ElementsById works look here: https://jsfiddle.net/alejoblue/co7dq1yt/1/

Comment: there are few  problems in your code, check here the working 
 one https://codepen.io/upretim/pen/VwKKjww instead of test.addEventListener use test[0].addEventListener because test is an array of nodes.

Comment: i see the sample you send works fine. I put on my site but it didn't work:
https://nycphoto.pixl.work/
im getting to think that im targeting the wrong element

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the `header` element.  On scroll, the `style` property of the document header is changing.  Look:

[image]

<sup>sorry for the bad quality, upload size is maxed at 2MB</sup>

Without getting into *too* much detail, one thing that I see is that the height of the header is being reduced to only contain the main header.  When the larger blue subheader is visible, part of that is because the `style.height` of the header is made to be much larger.  Additionally, the first child of the header is a div with id `7905`, and that seems to be what you need to target to modify the opacity of the larger blue header.  You need to target *that* div:

```js
const blueBannerContainer = document.getElementById('7905')
```

But your event handlers will also need to account for the height of the `header` element.  `display: block` won't really help you here.

Comment: the sticky header is ok, that's the way it should work. The problem is that the javascript is not being applied, im not sure ig im getting the right element