# Why my html(Javascript) code doesn't work in vsCode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, visual-studio-code

this is a simple code that helps HTML to execute a code that will open a box-modal. But for whatever reason, it doesn't seem to do anything while I write it in Vscode but it works perfectly fine while I write it in 'code-pen'. pls, tell meWhy my javascript is not working like that?

```
//javascript
const open = document.getElementById('click');
const Skill = document.getElementsByClassName('Skill');
open.addEventListener('click' , function() {
    Skill.classList.add('show');
});
```

```
//html
  
<nav class="nav-bar">
    <div class="Logocontainer">
 <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">T&S</a></h1>
</div>
 <ul class="Menu">
     <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
     <li id="click"><a href="#" id="click">My Skills</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about me">About Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
});
```

```
//css
.Skill{
    display: flex;
     margin-left: 500px;
     background-color: black;
     width: 800px;
     height: 200px;
     border-radius:10px;
     color: white;
     font-weight: bold;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     display: none;
    }
.Skill.show{
  display:block;
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect us to do to help you here? We don't know what your html or css looks like... Are you getting any errors? Is the class being applied in the html? We need an [mcve]  to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Answer (score -1):

`getElementsByClassName` retrieves a list, as you can see per the name: "elements". Plural.

change

```
const Skill = document.getElementsByClassName('Skill')
```

to

```
const Skill = document.getElementsByClassName('Skill')[0];
```

in order to access the first element with class "skill".

Comment: If that's the problem, this is a duplicate of, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Comment: The class 'skill' is not set as an array it's a list for my 'nav' bar

Comment: getElementsByClassName  returns a list of all elements found with the class "skill" @SAM