# Creating a simple responsive javascript toggle

Tags: javascript, toggle, responsive, togglebutton

For a sidemenu i've created a toggle with a simple javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("left");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

This works fine on large screens, but on a mobile/smaller device i'd like to start with the sidemenu closed. I've added css to change the display from 'block' to 'none':

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
    #left {
        z-index:10;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display:none;
    }
}
```

When you initially open the page on a small device **you have to click the menubutton twice**  to activate the script. How could i add a 2nd check to the script to include width? I thought something with adding '[matchmedia](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_matchmedia.asp)' but can't get it to work.

I've created a basic fiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/zouLf8ey/1/

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("left");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#left {
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-right: 1px solid #ededed;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #left {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: none;
  }
}

#right {
  width: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}
```

```html
<div class="scherm">
  <div class="schermtekst">
    <button id="menu-toggle" title="show/hide index" onclick="myFunction()">Menu</button>
    <div id="left">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a> </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <h1>
        <a name=""></a>Title
      </h1>
      <p>
        Good: When the screen is smaller than 600px the menu is hidden. With one click on 'menu' the toggle opens the menu. <br/> Bad: When the screen is larger than 600px you have to click the 'menu' button twice. After that all works fine. This is due
        to the difference between display 'none' and 'block'. (on a smaller screen i don't want to clutter the layout with the menu in sight. <br/>
        <em>How can i properly change the script below in the html? I tried with setting an if for width &#38;&#38; display: block</em></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Cheers, Ed'

Comment: I'd suggest using a class to toggle the display, and then check for the existence of the class. Or compute the style of the div `getComputedStyle(x).display`

Comment: Thanks, i tried to use 'element.classList.toggle'. Then another class is added so i can change the display from 'none' to 'display'. But i believe i should change the class instead of adding one, right?
See my changed fiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/u2br5Lds/ . But now i need to use '!important' to overrule the display state. That can't be good.

Comment: _"But now i need to use '!important' to overrule the display state"_ - no you don't. Don't use IDs, use classes instead

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction (no expert here, au contraire), now i found i missed the '[0]' after getElementsByClassName to get the proper class:
`function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementsByClassName("left")[0];
   element.classList.toggle("rwd-toggle");
}`
found the info @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name. I read 'querySelector' has broader browser support, so i guess i can dive into that now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var x = document.getElementById("left");
    function myFunction() {
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    window.onresize = function(){
        if(window.screen.availWidth <= 425){
            x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
#left {
    height:calc(100% - 40px);
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display:block;
    padding:12px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ededed;
    border-right:1px solid #ededed;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
    #left {
        z-index:10;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display:none;
    }
}

#right {
    width:auto;
    height:calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display:block;
    padding:12px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ededed;

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="scherm">
        <div class="schermtekst">
        <button id="menu-toggle" title="show/hide index" onclick="myFunction()">Menu</button>
        <div id="left">
                <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 4</a> </li>
</ul>

     </div>
    <div id="right">
                    <h1>
                    <a name=""></a>Title 
                </h1>
                <p>
                Good: When the screen is smaller than 600px the menu is hidden. With one click on 'menu' the toggle opens the menu. <br/> Bad: When the screen is larger than 600px you have to click the 'menu' button twice. After that all works fine. This is due to the difference between display 'none' and 'block'. (on a smaller screen i don't want to clutter the layout with the menu in sight. <br/> 
        <em>How can i properly change the script below in the html? I tried with setting an if for width &#38;&#38; display: block</em></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**strong text**
use window.resize method

Comment: this still doesn't work since `onresize` event isn't fired if the device is _already_ smaller than 425

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Muthukumar, but i have to agree with evolutionxbox here.